# How do I edit variables and update content of a view component using a button within the same component?

Tags: asp.net, razor

Summary: I have a view component with buttons which need to be able to change the details displayed in the rest of the component on click, but i can't figure out how to update the components content and data using an element within the component.

I am using asp.net razor pages to make a simple UI which displays various info grabbed from a JSON file, no database connection or POST functionality necessary.

I want the block of html that displays the data to be a reusable component, so i don't have to rewrite it every time i want to show a different entry in the file. From my research, there are a few options: HTML components, tag helpers, razor components, partial views, and view components. I chose to use a view component since the other options all seemed either outdated or not capable enough to achieve what i wanted. That is, with the exception of razor components, which require blazor to function fully which would also require me to learn a whole new framework and retrofit my program to work for it.

My view component functions to the point where i can invoke it from Index.cs and the component shows all the data from the first log in the list, as desired.

My intention: the default entryNo value is 0, so the component shows the title and date from the first log entry. When a user clicks the "Next" button (inside the component), entryNo becomes 1, and the component shows the title and date of the second entry in the log file.

ViewComponent.cshtml:

```
@model FullLog

@{ int entryIndLocal = 0; }

<div>
    <div>@Model[entryNo].Title</div>
    <div>@Model[entryNo].Date</div>
    <button onclick={entryNo++}>Next</button>
</div>
```

What i've tried:

- Setting the entryNo value in the view's .cs file and including a function to increment that value when called. I couldn't figure out how to call the function from the cshtml.
- Initialising the entryNo variable from within the cshtml file, with the intention of the adding `onclick={@entryNo++}`. This didn't work either.

Comment: You cannot change the C# variable in  the view.If you want to change it,you can try to submit the data to backend and refresh the view.

Comment: @YiyiYou 
OK, good to know. I've done some research on how to send data from a view to the controller, but everything i find seems to overcomplicate things with additional frameworks and tools like ajax or jquery. 

Could you suggest a method i can look into to pass data from the View component to its controller?